# Show and Hide uitableviewcells in uitableview in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

The highlighted region in image would be hide/show after tapping view below (with label Additional Cards), is there any library in `iOS` to do that? if not then how can it be done?

[image: Prototype image for hide/show uitableview Cell]

Comment: You use this library  https://github.com/Ramotion/folding-cell . This library easy to use and efficient for folding the tableview cell (expanding and collapse )@Ali Murad


  [1]:

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to expand and collapses tableview cells.However abouv library is also good. But,if you want to learn how to do that without any library and there are many things about tableview that you might get helpful in future.
Demo and Link to do Step by step https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells.

Also, you can download demo directly from here.https://github.com/soapyigu/Swift30Projects/tree/master/Project%2005%20-%20Artistry  .You will also found the download link on the first url i gave you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom view and use it as footerview for your tableView. Add a tap recognizer (or you can add button) to it so that when the user taps it you can modify your dataSource. See below:

```
protocol FooterDelegate {
    func requestedToDisplayMoreItemsFrom(footer: Footer, display:Bool)
}
class Footer: UIView {
    var delegate : FooterDelegate?
    var section : Int?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        let tapReco = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(Footer.tapped))
        /*
        . setup
        . codes 
        . here
        .
        */
    }

    func tapped() {
        if let del = delegate {
            del.requestedToDisplayMoreItemsFrom(footer: self, display: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how to use it. I will not post any code on how to display it as footerView,Im pretty sure you can write that for yourself, if not there are many resources you can find out there.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, FooterDelegate {
    var dataSource = [[String],[String]]

    func requestedToDisplayMoreItemsFrom(footer: Footer, display: Bool) {
        if display {
            self.dataSource[footer.section!].append("item1")
            self.dataSource[footer.section!].append("item2")
            self.dataSource[footer.section!].append("item3")
        } else {
            self.dataSource[footer.section!].removeLast()
            self.dataSource[footer.section!].removeLast()
            self.dataSource[footer.section!].removeLast()
        }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert cells use this code

```
var cells: [Any] = [IndexPath(row: 1, section: 2), IndexPath(row: 2, section: 2)]
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setCompletionBlock({() -> Void in
    tableView.reloadData()
})
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.insertRows(at: cells, with: .fade)
tableView.endUpdates()
CATransaction.commit()
```

To delete cells use code..

```
var cells: [Any] = [IndexPath(row: 1, section: 2), IndexPath(row: 2, section: 2)]
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setCompletionBlock({() -> Void in
    tableView.reloadData()
})
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.deleteRows(at: cells, with: .fade)
tableView.endUpdates()
CATransaction.commit()
```